# Python threaded tkinter GUI unresponsive unless sleep time is used.

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I'm using python 2.7 and have built a UI using Tkinter. I'm using threads and queues to keep the UI responsive while the main script is working. The basic summary is the script reads a text file, parses out some information on it and puts that info in a dictionary and a list in the dictionary, then uses that info to send TCP modbus request (using pyModbus). It then writes the responses/results to a text file. The results also get printed a Text widget included in the UI. The updates to the Text widget is handled by the mainloop.

I'm still fairly new to threads and queues and I'm having trouble figuring out this issue.

---

The problem I'm running into is I need to include a ~10ms sleep after it loops through each item in the list for the UI to remain responsive. If I include the sleep time it works as expected, if not it freezes up until the threaded process is finished then updates the UI all at once (as it would if threads weren't used). The 10ms sleep can be slightly shorter. Any amount longer also works.

Here's the code that handles updating the log:

```
textQueue = Queue.Queue()

def TextDisplay(message, disTime="false", myColor="black", bgColor="white"):
    textQueue.put([message, disTime, myColor, bgColor])

class LogUI:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master

        '''other ui elements, not relevent'''

        self.mainLogFrame = Frame(self.master)
        self.mainLogFrame.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand="yes", padx=5, pady=2)

        self.logText = Text(self.mainLogFrame, height=2)
        self.logText.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand="yes", padx=5, pady=2)

        self.ThreadSafeTextDisplay()

    def ThreadSafeTextDisplay(self):
        while not textQueue.empty():
            tempText = textQueue.get(0)
            message = tempText[0]
            disTime = tempText[1]
            myColor = tempText[2]
            bgColor =  tempText[3]

            message = str(message) + "\n"

            '''bunch of formating stuff'''

            logUI.logText.insert(END, message)
            print message
            #NOTE: tried to include a sleep time here, no effect

        self.logText.after(10, self.ThreadSafeTextDisplay)
```

Here's the non-threaded function that's called when the user clicks a button.

```
def ParseInputFile():
    '''non-threaded function, called when user clicks button'''
    inputList = []

    inputFile = mainUI.fullInFileEntry.get()
    with open(inputFile, 'r') as myInput:
        '''open file and put contents in list'''
        for line in myInput:
            inputList.append(line.strip())

    outFile = mainUI.outFileEntry.get().strip() + '.txt'

    i = 1
    tableBol = False
    inputDict = {}
    inputKeys = []
    tableID = None
    for item in inputList:
        '''parses out inputKeys, inputDict using regular expressions'''

    runInputGetQueue.put([inputKeys, inputDict, outFile, inputFile])
```

Here's the threaded function that receives the parsed information and handles the modbus request (note: i tried commenting out the actual modbus request, no effect):

```
def RunInputThread():
    time.sleep(.1)
    while 1:
        while not runInputGetQueue.empty():
            tempGet = runInputGetQueue.get(0)
            inputKeys = tempGet[0]
            inputDict = tempGet[1]
            outFile = tempGet[2]
            inputFile = tempGet[3]

            outFile = open(outFile, 'w')

            TextDisplay('< Start of %s input file > ' % inputFile, True, 'blue')

            for key in inputKeys:
                '''loops through the keys in the dictionary'''
                TextDisplay(key) #just used as an example.
                for lineIndex in range(len(inputDict[key]['tableLines'])):
                    '''lots of code that loops thorugh the lines of input file, frequently calls the TextDisplay() function'''
                    TextDisplay(inputDict[key][lineIndex]) #just used as an example.

                    time.sleep(0.01) #UI will become unresponseive if not included. 



            outFile.close()
        time.sleep(0.001)
```

Comment: the reason you need to add the sleep is because python threads aren't really threads, at least in cpython because of the GIL. as the main gui updates when it enters the `mainloop` the background thread needs to go into an idle state (either doing nothing or at least not holding the GIL) a sleep accomplishes this, your options to get around it are limited

Comment: Thanks, that makes perfect sense. After a little research it seems like multiprocessing can used instead of threading to get around this issue. Any idea if this is possible?

Comment: multithreading can be used, it just depends on what data needs to be passed back and forth how complicated it is, i believe there is a Queue object for multprocessing aswell, so may be worth looking into that and seeing if you can adapt what you're currently using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to get the UI mostly responsive. As stated in the comments above, the queue was receiving stuff to fast the function would be constantly working causing the UI to lock up. I made it so it will print at most 5 messages before taking a 1ms break and recalling the function which allows the UI to 'catch up.' The messages are printed almost as fast as they come in.

The UI will be slightly non-responsive if you move it or resize it. I have no issues interacting with other UI elements while this is running though.

You could also change the while loop to a if statement if you don't mind it being slow. The one process i ran went from 14 seconds with an if statement down to around 5 or 6 seconds using the code below. It would be same as if you changed the `pullCount` `break` point to 1 instead of 5.

```
def ThreadSafeTextDisplay(self):
    pullCount = 0
    while not textQueue.empty():
        pullCount += 1
        tempText = textQueue.get(0)
        message = tempText[0]
        disTime = tempText[1]
        myColor = tempText[2]
        bgColor =  tempText[3]

        message = str(message) + "\n"

        '''bunch of formatting stuff'''

        logUI.logText.insert(END, message)
        print message
        if pullCount >= 5: break  #you can change the 5 value to whatever you want, the higher the number the faster stuff will print but the UI will start to become unresponsive. 
    self.logText.after(1, self.ThreadSafeTextDisplay)
```